Non-observant father and binding minhagim
A Sephardic Jew cannot wear tefillin following Ashkenazi customs. Does this prohibition apply when the father of this Sephardic Jew was never observant, and this Sephardic Jew in question wants to do baal teshuvah? Another example: is a Sephardic Jew whose father was never observant prohibited from eating fish with milk, even if he performs baal teshuvah for a Chabad community (which allows eating fish with milk), for example?

Many (most?) Lubavitchers don't eat fish with milk either.

The premise that a Sephardic Jew should not wear Ashkenazic tefillin is the ruling of Rav Ovadia Yosef - others such as his son Rav Yaakov Yosef disagree.

Not eating fish with milk? If I understand  the point correctly that would prohibit lox (smoked salmon) and cream cheese.

On eating lox and cream cheese see https://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/4866
